# PHP does not process if there is no data in return for the date

Tags: php, if-statement

I can't operate on two databases.
If there is a data equal to the date, I print the average in a column.
If there is no data equal to the date, I get the error below.
I need to type an "else" but when I type I can't get it to run.
My codes are as follows;

```
                    <?php
                         $Sor = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM yemeklistesi");
                    //burada satırları dizi olarak çektik
                        $rows = $Sor->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
                        foreach ($rows as $row) {
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $kullaniciadi = $row['yemek'];
                        $sifre = $row['tarih'];
                 ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['yemek']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['tarih']; ?></td>
                        <td style="background-color: green; color:#fff; font-size:20px;">
                            <?php

                                    // echo strtotime($row['tarih']);
                                $bilgiler = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM yemekhane_anket");
                                $bilgilercek=$bilgiler->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                    $say = 0;
                                    $mem = 0;
                                 foreach ($bilgilercek as $row2) {
                                    $a = strtotime($row2['tarih']);
                                    if(strval($row['tarih']) == strval(date('Y-m-d',$a))){
                                        $say = $say + 1;
                                    }
                                    if(strval($row['tarih']) == strval(date('Y-m-d',$a)) && strval($row2['memnuniyet_durumu']) == '1'){
                                        $mem = $mem + 1;
                                    }
                                 }
                                echo round(intval($mem) * 100/intval($say));
                             ?>
                        %</td>

                    </tr>
               <?php }

                ?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting when you type else statement? Please post your code which is giving an error so it will be easier for people to help

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to check the values are not empty before the condition or inside it, and are capable of creating dateTime object in the specific format

```
date_create_from_format(string $format, string $datetime, ?DateTimeZone $timezone = null): DateTime|false
```

The above will return the date time object if the date time string is capable of creating it, If not it will return a **FALSE** boolean value. With this you can execute your else part.